# XML get value from nextNode

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am trying to get a value from a node after my selected node. So far I have been able to get the whole node info as a var but I am stuck on how to get only the value out.

my xml looks like so

```
<COLUMN>
<NAME>Addr1</NAME>
<VALUE>1234 my street</VALUE>
</COLUMN>
```

and I getting the node like this

```
var address = (from c in contactInfo.Descendants("NAME")
                                   where c.Value == "Addr1"
                               select c.NextNode).Single();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
(address as XElement).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

`NextNode` returns an `XNode`, while you need an `XElement`:

```
var address = (from c in doc.Descendants("NAME")
    where c.Value == "Addr1"
    select c.NextNode).OfType<XElement>().Single().Value;
```

I would rather avoid putting it all on one line and do something like the following to add some extra checks:

```
var address = (from c in doc.Descendants("NAME")
                where c.Value == "Addr1"
                select c.NextNode).Single();
var element = address as XElement;
if (element != null) {
    string value = element.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var node = contactInfo.Descendants("COLUMN")
                  .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Element("NAME").Value.Equals("Addr1"))

if (node != null)
     var result = node.Element("VALUE").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select `COLUMN` element instead of searching for `NAME` elements:

```
var address = (from c in contactInfo.Descendants("COLUMN")
               where (string)c.Element("NAME") == "Addr1"
               select (string)c.Element("VALUE")).Single();
```

Same with method syntax:

```
var address = contactInfo.Descendants("COLUMN")
                         .Where(c => (string)c.Element("NAME") == "Addr1")
                         .Select(c => (string)c.Element("VALUE"))
                         .Single();
```

Also you should be completely sure that there always exist exactly one column element with name `Addr1`. Otherwise `Single()` will throw an exception.